# mapping complex object with automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I convert `IEnumerable<Category>` to `IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>` with this definition

```
public class Category
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    }

public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Guid  CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have done like this

```
public static IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> ConvertToCategoryViewModelList(this IEnumerable<Category> category)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>>(category);
```

but it doesn't map Id to CategoryId and also I don't want to have CreationTime in CategoryVeiwModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either property names should match, or you have to override the mapping for the `Id`. Also you have to explicitly `Ignore` the `CreationTime`:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
.ForMember(x => x.CategoryId, src => src.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
.ForSourceMember(x => x.CreationTime, y => y.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use inheritance and down cast (or is it up casting)

```
public class Category : CategoryViewModel
{
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Guid  CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry but Category is in Model and CategoryViewModel is in Service , Model Should NOT see the ViewModel!

Comment: then maybe you want the classes be private? or at least the properties?

Comment: No I just want to cast properties of a class to another with different names, that's all